# Precedence of profile files

Tags: linux, bash, profile

On my work machine (which I do not have sudo access on), I change my `$PATH` variable in my `~/.profile`. However, I am finding that some scripts in `/etc/profile.d` are changing the path further, making my changes useless.

Can I change the order of execution so that my `~/.profile` is executed last? If not, where can I set my `$PATH` and be sure that my path is not overwritten (`.bashrc` is not an option because I want to change path in the desktop environment as well as the shell).

I am running CentOS 7 with MATE Desktop.

Comment: No you can't change the order. See [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Comment: Do you have a `~/.bash_profile` or a `~/bash_login`?

Comment: No, I don't. The script from `/etc/profile.d` are the one that are running.

Comment: Your `.profile` is already executed last. Assuming it's executed at all, that is.